# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un vector (ya creado) como nueva fila a un dataframe siendo el nombre de la nueva fila el del vector?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando añadir un vector a un data frame pero añdiendo directamente el nombre del vector a la nueva fila en vez del número del índice.

Paso código:

```
state.df = as.data.frame(state.x77)
Medias = apply(state.df, MARGIN = 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
state.df = data.frame(state.df, Medias)
rbind(state.df, Medias)
```

Como veis el vector "Medias" se añade al df con el índice 51 en vez de con el nombre "Medias".

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo directamente que no sea asignarle ese nombre a la fila posteriormente?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Firegust, bienvenido a stackoverflow. Lo que deseas hacer es agregar una fila o una columna, o ambas? Aunque mencionas que la nueva fila se agrega en el índice 51, lo pregunto porque en el tercer reglón del código agregas una columna..

Comment: Bienvenido Firegust a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `rowname` es un atributo de un `data.frame` no de un vector, si quieres "heredar" el nombre de fila, debería crear un `data.frame` para los valores de las medias y recién ahí hacer el `rbind()`:

```
Medias = data.frame(rbind(colMeans(state.df)), 
                    row.names="Medias", 
                    check.names = FALSE)

rbind(state.df, Medias)
```

Con `row.names="Medias"` establecemos el nombre de fila, usamos `colMeans()` que es más rápido y cómodo que el `apply()` y `check.names = FALSE` para que no se normalicen los nombres de columnas y se respeten los originales